# CONCAT_WS rows in JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

i have tables

```
profiles (id, name, deleted)
categories (id, name, deleted)
profiles_categories (id, profile_id, category_id, , deleted)
```

I have **wrong** query

```
SELECT p.id, p.name CONCAT_WS(', ', c.name) AS keywords_categories
FROM profiles p
LEFT JOIN profiles_categories pc ON p.id = pc.profile_id
LEFT JOIN categories c ON pc.id = c.id
WHERE p.deleted = FALSE
```

So, i want have result with **all** `profiles` with concan `categories.name`.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to return a comma separated list of `categories` for each profile?  Or what is the result that you want displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not exactly clear but it seems like you actually want to use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which will create a comma separated list of all categories for each profile:

```
SELECT p.id, 
  p.name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(c.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS keywords_categories
FROM profiles p
LEFT JOIN profiles_categories pc ON p.id = pc.profile_id
LEFT JOIN categories c ON pc.id = c.id
WHERE p.deleted = FALSE 
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

Comment: nice, but this code return only first profile where have categories, that another who isn't have categories not displayed...

Comment: @AlexKiselev I don't understand your question, this returns all profiles even if there is no category. See this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaaec/2